# How to display the values of the attributes of the data queried and retrieved by Ajax call in django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am trying to query the database based on what the user has clicked on the page and display the data retrieved by it without refreshing the page. I am using Ajax for this. Let me show you the codes

**html**

```
<label for="landacq" class="civil-label">Land Acquisation Cases</label>
<input class="civil-category" type="radio" name="civil-cat" id="landacq" value="land acquisation" hidden>

<label for="sc" class="civil-label">Supreme Court</label>
<input class="civil-court" type="radio" name="civil-court" id="sc" value="supreme court" hidden>

<label for="limitation" class="civil-label">Limitation</label>
<input class="civil-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-law-type" id="limitation" value="limitation" hidden>
```

**js**

```
for (i = 0; i < lawTypeInput.length; i++) {
  lawTypeInput[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    cat = civilCatval;
    court = civilCourtval;
    lawT = civillawTypeval;
    console.log("this is from ajax : ", cat, court, lawT);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
      mode: "same-origin", // Do not send CSRF token to another domain.
      url: "civil",
      data: {
        "cat[]": civilCatval,
        "court[]": civilCourtval,
        "lawT[]": civillawTypeval,
      },
      success: function (query) {
        showCivilQ(query);
        // console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });
  });
}

function showCivilQ(query) {
  q.textContent = query;
  console.log(query);
}
```

So here for example, if the user the click the radio button in the html, the values are grabbed by in js file and then sent to the url mentioned as a POST request. There these values are use to filter the database and return the objects like this

**views.py**

```
def civil_home(request):
    
    if request.is_ajax():
    
      get_cat = request.POST.get('cat[]')
      get_court = request.POST.get('court[]')
      get_lawT = request.POST.get('lawT[]')

      query = Citation.objects.filter(law_type__contains ='civil' ,sub_law_type__contains= get_cat, court_name__contains = get_court, law_category__contains = get_lawT)

      return HttpResponse(query)
    else:
      subuser = request.user

      subscription = UserSubscription.objects.filter(user = subuser, is_active = True)

      context = {
        'usersub': subscription,
      }
    

      return render(request, 'civil/civil_home.html', context)
```

This is the result I am getting which is correct.

[image: result of what I am getting]

My Question is these objects contain attributes having some values in for eg, title, headnote etc. How can I display these attributes in the html rather than displaying the object names returned as shown in the Image like title of the citation, headnote of the citation etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to return a `json` object instead of the `query` resultset; because Ajax works well with json

You need a function that translates a Citation object into a dictionary (change it based on your real attributes). All elements must be translated into strings (see date example)

```
def citation_as_dict(item):
    return {
        "attribute1": item.attribute1,
        "attribute2": item.attribute2,
        "date1":  item.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    }
```

This dictionary must be translated into a json through `import json` package

```
def civil_home(request):
    
    if request.is_ajax():
    
      get_cat = request.POST.get('cat[]')
      get_court = request.POST.get('court[]')
      get_lawT = request.POST.get('lawT[]')

      query = Citation.objects.filter(law_type__contains ='civil' ,sub_law_type__contains= get_cat, court_name__contains = get_court, law_category__contains = get_lawT)

      response_dict = [citation_as_dict(obj) for obj in query]
      response_json = json.dumps({"data": response_dict})
      return HttpResponse(response_json, content_type='application/json')

    else:
      subuser = request.user

      subscription = UserSubscription.objects.filter(user = subuser, is_active = True)

      context = {
        'usersub': subscription,
      }
    

      return render(request, 'civil/civil_home.html', context)
```

In your HTML page you should be able to parse the response as a normal JSON object

Comment: Will you please check the answer that I have posted, if that is a correct way to go about it or not?

Comment: it seems ok too +1

Answer (score 1):

I figured out another way to do it, which is giving me the required results too.

Here I am filtering the values of the query, and then converting it to a list and passing it as a JsonResponse
**views.py**

```
def civil_home(request):
    
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
    
      get_cat = request.POST.get('cat[]')
      get_court = request.POST.get('court[]')
      get_lawT = request.POST.get('lawT[]')

      query = Citation.objects.values().filter(law_type__contains ='civil' ,sub_law_type__contains= get_cat, court_name__contains = get_court, law_category__contains = get_lawT)

      result = list(query)

      return JsonResponse({"status": "success", "result": result})
    
    else:
      subuser = request.user

      subscription = UserSubscription.objects.filter(user = subuser, is_active = True)

      context = {
        'usersub': subscription,
      }
    

      return render(request, 'civil/civil_home.html', context)
```

And then I am recieving the reponse here and iterrating over it to print the attributes in the html
**js**

```
for (i = 0; i < lawTypeInput.length; i++) {
  lawTypeInput[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    cat = civilCatval;
    court = civilCourtval;
    lawT = civillawTypeval;
    console.log("this is from ajax : ", cat, court, lawT);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
      mode: "same-origin", // Do not send CSRF token to another domain.
      url: "civil",
      data: {
        "cat[]": civilCatval,
        "court[]": civilCourtval,
        "lawT[]": civillawTypeval,
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.result);
        civilData = response.result;
        if ((response.status = "success")) {
          $("#queryResult").empty();
          for (i = 0; i < civilData.length; i++) {
            $("#queryResult").append(
              `
              <a href="">${civilData[i].title}</a>
              <p>${civilData[i].headnote}</p>
            `
            );
          }
        } else {
          $("#queryResult").empty();
          $("#queryResult").append(
            `
              <p>No Citations Found</p>
            `
          );
        }
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });
  });
}
```

A csrf_token can be mentioned at the top of the html page and then it can be passed in the header to avoid any conflict.